Django's filter clears foreign keys
In views.py, if I defining variable like clients_list = Clients.objects.all() and reading them in html like {{ clients_list }} then I get all data correct.
But if I make filtering like clients_list = Clients.objects.filter(cli_account='123').values() then all the foreign keys are converted to integers and not displayed if requested in html (only in all queryset).
I need to filter clients list but keep all foreign keys as they were unfiltered, not integer - strings.
p.s.: if I trying to get {{ obj.cli_status }} in the first version, I get "ready", but in the second version i get blank (an integer in queryset)

if I type in html {{ obj.cli_responcible.manager_name }} i get its string without filtering, but when filtering - that thing returns blank

When passing clients in views.py I used this line:
clients_list = Clients.objects.filter(cli_account='123').values()

but in order to work well, the end should be like this:
clients_list = Clients.objects.filter(cli_account='123').select_related('cli_status')

I don't know why, but all foreign keys (cli_status and others) now displayed as text and work fine now
